# ASP.NET MVC 2 + EF4 - what are my in-site text search options?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, full-text-search, search-engine, sql-server-2008-r2

The question title just about says it all.  I have a ASP.NET MVC 2 site built on EF 4.0, and am wondering what my options are for having in-site text search capabilities.  Are there 3rd party plugins?  Do I need to roll my own with whatever SQL Server 2008 R2 has for a `LIKE` command + joins or LINQ statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the [SQL 2008 FTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) but it seems there are [problems with it](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/11/sql-2008-full-text-search-problems/) so [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) seems like a good solution.